# Root of a polynomial with Complex coefficient

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the complex polynomial
$P(x)= x^6+ix^4+1$ where $i=√(-1)$
. How to show that $P$ has atleast three zeroes of the form $\alpha+i\beta$ with $\beta<0 , \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

What I have done is,

$P(x)$ doesn't have any real root. Since, $x^6+ix^4+1=0\implies(x^6+ix^4+1)(x^6-ix^4+1)=0\implies x^{12}+2x^6+x^8+1=0$
Observe that using Descartes' rule of signs there is no sign change in the last equation. Therefore the equation $x^{12}+2x^6+x^8+1=0$ has no real root. So $P(x)$ also has no real root.
But I am unable to prove further question.

Comment: Please add relevant context eg  source of the problem, your own ideas for solution. As of now this is just the problem statement.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there are no real roots since $\Re P(x)=x^6+1>0$ for $x$ real.

But if $x$ is a root then $-x$ is a root so by the above precisely $3$ roots have negative imaginary part and $3$ have positive imaginary part

Answer (score 3):

If $z$ is root then $-z$ is also a root.
Let $z=p$ a real number then we have $p^6+ip^2+1=\implies p^6+1=0 \& p^2=0$ which are mutually inconsitent.

Next, let $z=iq$ where $q$ is real then we have $-q^3+1=0 \& q^2=0$ which are again mutually inconsistent.

Therefore the given eq. has neither purely real nor purely imaginary roots.

So all roots will be pairs like $u+iv, \& -u-iv$ where $u,v \ne 0$.